# bit operations in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I would like to ask you how I can do bit operations &,<<,>>,| in assembly. I know about shift and Rotate opinion, but I don't know hot to do it with this. I'm able to write this in C but I don't know how to implement in assembly. Could you please help me with this?

**EDIT**: For Intel x86

Thanks

```
void shifting_in_C(unsigned short n)
{
    unsigned char a = n & 255;
    unsigned char b = n >>8;
    unsigned char c =  (n << 8) 
    unsigned char d = (n << 8) | 255;
}
```

Comment: Compile the _C_ code and look at the generated assembly code?

Comment: For which CPU? Find its instructions manual

Comment: Edited. For Intel x86

Comment: And so what happened when you tried it?  What did you find when you looked at the x86 reference documentation?

Comment: Looking at the patterns, is your real case a bitroll?

Answer (score 3):

You need to think a moment about what you are trying to accomplish.  It's a common belief that "if I can write it in assembler, it will be faster."  This seems like it would make sense since assembler is the language the processor actually speaks, right?

However that ignores the fact that the purpose of a compiler is to turn high level languages into assembler.  And compilers know all sorts of tricks and quirks about how to wring the best performance out of processors that it would take you ages to master.

So if the goal is to make part of your code run faster by writing it in assembler, you need to be sure you can write assembler better than the wizards who write compilers.  It can happen.  But more commonly the code you write yourself is going to be slower.

But if the goal is to learn more about computers and assembler, then go for it.

That said...

The x86 assembler instructions you are looking for are pretty obvious once you start looking thru the available instructions.  [Here's](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) an x86 instruction reference (not necessarily the best, just the first one google offered).

Looking at your example:

- Paging thru the list we see the `AND` instruction described as "Logical AND"
- `SHR` which they describe as "Shift" but more correctly would be described as "Shift Right."
- `SHL` which is also described as "Shift" but is actually "Shift Left."
- Your last example contains 2 operations.  The first is another `SHL`, and the second is an `OR`.

If you plan to do much work in assembler, you should spend some time paging thru a reference to become familiar with the various instructions.

FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

```
void shifting_in_C(unsigned short n)
{
    unsigned char a = n & 255;
    unsigned char b = n >>8;
    unsigned char c =  (n << 8) 
    unsigned char d = (n << 8) | 255;
}


push ebx
; unsigned char a = n & 255;
mov al, [esp + 8]
; unsigned char b = n >>8;
mov bl, [esp + 9]
; unsigned char c =  (n << 8) 
xor cl, cl   ;(constant overflow)
; unsigned char d = (n << 8) | 255;
xor dl, dl   ;(constant overflow)
dec dl
pop ebx
ret
```

I think you want this:

```
unsigned short bswap16(unsigned short n)
{
    return ((n & 0xFF) << 8) | (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
}

mov ax, [esp + 4]
xchg al, ah
ret
```

Comment: If it is swapping bytes @Matey is looking for, we should also consider `__builtin_bswap16` or [`_byteswap_ushort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177.aspx) (depending on compiler).